# How to retrieve a node's headline/title for a known org-id?

Tags: org-mode

I would like to make and insert a link `[[id:retrieved-id][retrieved-title]]`.

`retrieved-id` is returned by selecting the subtree I want from a list of titles. The list, selection and returned ID is accomplished by `(org-id-get-with-outline-path-completion org-refile-targets)`.

`org-id-get-with-outline-path-completion` returns the ID but not the text of my selection. How do I retrieve the title/headline text associated with `retrieved-id`?

Comment: This seems a bit circular to me: you want to find the text of the headline that has a certain ID, but you get the ID by basically specifying the headline - am I missing something?

Comment: I edited the OP to clarify. I am specify the headline by choosing from a list. What I select is not returned by `org-id-get-with-outline-path-completion`. It only returns the `ID`, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to approach this, but starting from `org-id-get-with-outline-path-completion` the first thing I can come up with is using

```lisp
(defun insert-id-link ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((id (org-id-get-with-outline-path-completion)))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (org-find-entry-with-id id)))
    (insert (org-link-make-string (concat "id:" id)
                                  (org-get-heading)))))
```

(I am not sure if you really need to add the `org-refile-targets`, but if so, then simply add it).

Comment: If I understand the gist of it, the function has to 'visit' the subtree using `org-find-entry-with-id` to get its headline/title using `org-entry-get`. The `save-excursion` does the visiting in the background, i.e., I won't see buffer changes as the function executes. Is that an accurate understanding of your function?

Comment: Is there a way to get the title by looking up the hash table of org-IDs and their locations? Isn't that how `org-find-entry-with-id` finds where to go?

Comment: No, `org-find-entry-with-id` searches the current buffer for ID properties.

Comment: The hash table contains entries with the ID as index and the filename as value. So the file has to be visited in order to find the  headline with the required ID.

Comment: @dalanicolai: does this work for anything other than the current file? I would expect to see `org-id-find` called.

Comment: @NickD I just provided the most straightforward (for me) solution to the question. I did not know all the options to get the entry by i.d. (although I knew there were more), but this 'first step' was suggested in the question, so I just started from there. And because of this suggestion, I concluded that the question was about searching within the current file only. Indeed, the current answer does not work for getting the title from other files than the current one.

Comment: @midas0441 Using `C-h f` you can read the docstring of save-excursion, that is all I know about it.

Comment: @NickD `org-id-find` did also not seem to be an option as the question states that the ID is obtained by selecting from a list of titles (also therefore I assumed the question was about searching in the current file only)

Comment: @midas0441 Although it was a nice suggestion, the `org-entry-get` was not in my original answer (see [revisions](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/posts/73635/revisions)), and it is also not part of the current version of the answer.